# javascript removeClass wildcard, less specific pattern

Tags: jquery, regex, wildcard

In the element I have:

```
<span class="fa fa-address-book fa-user fa-4x fa-5x fa-lg"></span>
```

I need to remove this (fa-address-book and fa-user [font-awesome icons-names]), and keep it that way:

Note: (fa-address-book and fa-user) is dynamic, can be anyone.

```
<span class="fa fa-4x fa-5x fa-lg"></span>
```

My jQuery:

```
$(".button").click(function(e) {

    var regexp_order = /(^|\s)fa-\S+|(?=fa-4x)|(?=fa-5x)|(?=fa-lg)|(?=fa)/;
    var regexp = new RegExp(regexp_order, "g");

    $("#demo").removeClass (function (index, className) {
        return (className.match (regexp) || []).join(' ');
    });

    var temporal = $("#demo").attr("class");
    $("#result").append(temporal);

});
```

I have a lot of problems. What am I doing wrong?

My jsFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/m79c1edr/15/

Comment: why do you need wild when you know what class to remove be straight with it

Comment: why you don't use "removeClass('fa-address-book fa-user')" directly?

Comment: because ("fa-address-book fa-user") is random dynamic in every session

Please help me.

Comment: remove all class then add the desired class like `$("#demo").attr('class', '').addClass("fa fa-4x fa-5x fa-lg");`

Comment: @RenatoRamosPuma glad its ok now happy coding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this regex, which removes all sub-strings that have more than 2 characters after `fa-` or `fa-cc` specifically

```
fa(?:-(?:cc|\w{3,}))+
```

**Explanation:**

- `fa` - Finds `fa` literally
- `(?:-\w{3,})+` - Finds `-` followed by three or more word character in a non-capture group whole of it one or more times to cover case `fa-address-book` case too.

**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zX9md4/2)**

**[Your updated JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/25jqp0mx/)**

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Pushpesh Kumar Rajwanshi thanks, it helps me a lot but there is a Font-Awesome icon (two-letter "fa-cc" icon).

I need to delete all the class of the element, except [fa, fa-lg, fa-2x, fa-3x, fa-4x, fa-5x]

Comment: @RenatoRamosPuma: Ok, if you need to specifically need to take care of `fa-cc` case or if you have more such similar cases, we can include them separately so they also get deleted. Best would be to find a pattern even in two letter words after `fa-` so the solution remains generic but if we don't find any pattern, then will have to include them specifically and will work at least for your current case.

Comment: @RenatoRamosPuma: I've updated my answer with new regex and new demo links for regex101 and jsfiddle. Please have a look and let me know if you still need anything further.

Comment: Thank you very much Pushpesh Kumar Rajwanshi, now if I found the definitive solution.

https://jsfiddle.net/z8b4y3tq/15/